# Apollo client persist cache not working

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a react app with apollo client. When a user logs in, I can query the client state and retrieve the user however, **when I refresh the page, the user data is no longer set**.

As you can see, I have my `index.js` file where I set the client and then pass that to my `ApolloProvider` which wraps my entire application.

```
// index.js

const client = () => {
  const cache = new InMemoryCache()

  persistCache({
    cache,
    storage: window.localStorage
  })

  return new ApolloClient({
    uri: graphQLUri,
    credentials: 'include',
    clientState: {
      defaults: {
        locale: "en-GB",
        user: {
          __typename: "User",
          isLoggedIn: false,
          username: "",
          salesChannel: "",
          fullName: ""
        }
      },
      typeDefs: `
        enum Locale {
          en-GB
          fr-FR
          nl-NL
        }
        type Query {
          locale: Locale
        }
      `
    },
    cache
  })
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client()}>
      <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

I should add that when I log `window.localStorage` after refreshing the page, I can see my logged in `user` object. When I query the user after refreshing the page, I only get the defaults that are set in clientState defaults.

Also, I know the `GET_USER` query works because after logging in and writing the user object the the cache, the `GET_USER` query runs and the user object is returned.

For reference, my `GET_USER` query is as so:

```
gql`
  {
    user @client {
      username
      salesChannel
      fullName
      isLoggedIn
    }
  }
`
```

Why does the user object not persist in the cache after reloading the page?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently changes to the `InMemoryCache` cache made with `writeQuery` and `writeFragment` **disappears after reloading the page**.

[Apollo Client docs:](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#writequery-and-writefragment)

> If you reload your environment then changes made with writeQuery and writeFragment will disappear.

Comment: Please explain further

Comment: What would you like to know?

Comment: Can you get the gql call to fetch from cache if the user refreshes the page? You explained they removed the functionality, but is his question possible?

Comment: Yes, check out apollo-cache-persist (https://blog.apollographql.com/announcing-apollo-cache-persist-cb05aec16325). This thread is only concerned about persisting cache after making manual writes to the cache with `writeQuery` and `writeFragment`, and it seems such persistance has never been supported.

Comment: I ended up using VueX, and Vuex-persist. This way state management was cleaner, and more stuctured, also its persisting offline, and on refreshes :) your answer really helped thanks nomadoda. Have some points